# matplotlib BrokenBarHcollection to shade over sundays in timeseries

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of datetimes and want to shade over all the Sundays. I'm inputting a `pandas.DateTimeIndex` for timespan which is a list of `np.datetime64` objects

```
def ShadeSunday(subplot,timespan):
    timelist = [date2num(time) for time in timespan]
    dayofweek = [int(datetime.date.weekday(time.to_datetime())) for time in timespan]
    collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(Weekdates, ymin=0, ymax=80000, where=dayofweek>5, facecolor='b', alpha='.05')
    subplot.add_collection(collection)
```

`datetime.date.weekday` is returning an integer (e.g. 6 for Sunday) so I have an x-value list of the times and a corresponding list of integer values for the day of the week. `BrokenBarHCollection.span_where` throws a type error:

```
"TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable" for the arguement 'where=dayofweek>5'
```

I've looked over a few examples and can't figure out how to get the 'where= ' to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should fix the error you are getting (hard to tell because I can not test the code you posted with out knowing your inputs)

```
def ShadeSunday(subplot,timespan):
    timelist = [date2num(time) for time in timespan]
    dayofweek_bool = [int(datetime.date.weekday(time.to_datetime())) > 5 for time in timespan]
    collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(Weekdates, ymin=0, ymax=80000, where=dayofweek_bool, facecolor='b', alpha='.05')
    subplot.add_collection(collection)
```

The problem you are having here is that lists do not broadcast boolean comparisons (but `numpy.array`s do).  Run `[1, 2, 3] > 322` in a REPL enviroment.